# Append 1/2 of the elements in one list to another list, in the form of a list

Tags: python, list, set, nested-lists

I have a list like this:

```
lst = [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {15, 19, 16, 21, 20, 45, 78}]
```

I want to create two new lists like this:

```
first_half = [{1, 2, 3}, {19, 15, 16}]
second_half = [{4, 5, 6}, {45, 21, 78, 20}]
```

I tried out something like this:

```
first_half_list = []
second_half_list = []
first_half = []
second_half = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    set2list = list(lst[i])
    print(set2list)
    for j in range(len(set2list)):
        if j < (len(set2list)//2):
            first_half_list.append(set2list[j])
        else:
            second_half_list.append(set2list[j])
    first_half.append(set(first_half_list))
    second_half.append(set(second_half_list))
    print(first_half, '\n')
```

But I get a weird result:

[image]

Any suggestions or help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't have two `19` values in a set...

Comment: And python sets are unordered, so there's no guarantee that converting `{15, 16, 19, 20, 45, 78}` to a list will give `[15, 16, 19, 20, 45, 78]`

Comment: I have edited the list. The order doesn't matter. I only want half of the elements in one list and another half in another list. Do you know how to do this now?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the results you want using a list comprehension, converting the sets to lists so that you can slice them, then converting the resultant lists back into sets:

```py
lst = [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {15, 19, 16, 21, 20, 45, 78}]

first_half = [set(list(s)[:len(s)//2]) for s in lst]
second_half = [set(list(s)[len(s)//2:]) for s in lst]

print(first_half, second_half, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {45, 78, 15}]
[{4, 5, 6}, {16, 19, 20, 21}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **sets** are not subscriptable, we should convert them into **lists** and then convert them back into **sets**.

```
lst = [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {15, 19, 16, 21, 20, 45, 78}]
a_lst, b_lst = [], []

for i in lst:
    i = list(i)
    a_lst.append(set(i[:len(i) // 2]))
    b_lst.append(set(i[len(i) // 2:]))

print(a_lst)
print(b_lst)
```

### Output

```
>>> [{1, 2, 3}, {45, 78, 15}]
>>> [{4, 5, 6}, {16, 19, 20, 21}]
```

Comment: But I need it as sets since I have to feed it in set form in another inbuilt function.

Comment: @PriyeshSharma Ok, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others, you need to convert sets into lists so that you can slice them
Below is the sample which works as per your desired result, however you study list comprehension to optimize this and make it generic

```
lst = [{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {15, 19, 16, 21, 20, 45, 78}]
a = list(lst[0])
b=list(lst[1])

first_elm = set(a[0:int(len(a)/2)])
sec_elem = set(b[0:int(len(b)/2)])
third_elem = set(a[int(len(a)/2):])
fourth_elem = set(b[int(len(b)/2):])

first_half = list([first_elm,sec_elem] )
first_half
second_half = list([third_elem,fourth_elem] )
second_half
```